# gphoto2 how to handle Out of Focus warning

Tags: python, python-logging, libgphoto2

Here is how I capture image with my camera

```
import logging
import gphoto2 as gp
def main():
    def callback(level, domain, string, data=None):
        print('Callback: level =', level, ', domain =', domain, ', string =', string)
        if data:
            print('Callback data:', data)

    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(levelname)s: %(name)s: %(message)s', level=logging.WARNING)
    callback_obj = gp.check_result(gp.use_python_logging())

    camera = gp.Camera()
    camera.init()
    try:
        camera_file_path = gp.check_result(camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE))
    except gp.GPhoto2Error as ex:
        print("callback: ", ex, ex.code, ex.message, ex.string)
    camera.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__" : exit(main())
```

If the camera is not able to focus it generates following error

```
...
WARNING: gphoto2: (ptp_usb_getresp [usb.c:466]) PTP_OC 0x90c8 receiving resp failed: Out of Focus (0xa002)
WARNING: gphoto2: (camera_nikon_capture [library.c:3153]) 'ret' failed: 'Out of Focus' (0xa002)
WARNING: gphoto2: (gp_context_error) Out of Focus
WARNING: gphoto2: (gp_camera_capture [gphoto2-camera.c:1340]) 'camera->functions->capture (camera, type, path, context)' failed: -1
('callback: ', GPhoto2Error('[-1] Unspecified error',), -1, '[-1] Unspecified error', 'Unspecified error')
```

The exception error code is `-1` but how can I capture `Out of Focus` warning?

**UPDATE**

Filtered out unnecessary errors from logs

```
import logging
import gphoto2 as gp
from datetime import datetime
def main():
    def callback(level, domain, string, data=None):
        err_codes = ("(0x2005)", "(0x2019)")
        if not string.decode().endswith(err_codes):
            print("[{0}] {1}: {2}".format(datetime.utcnow(), domain.decode(), string.decode()))
        if data:
            print('Callback data:', data)

    callback_obj = gp.check_result(gp.gp_log_add_func(gp.GP_LOG_ERROR, callback))
    camera = gp.Camera()
    try:
        camera.init()
    except gp.GPhoto2Error as err:
        exit(err.code)

    try:
        camera_file_path = camera.capture(gp.GP_CAPTURE_IMAGE)
    except gp.GPhoto2Error as err:
        exit(err.code)
    camera.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__" : exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined a callback function, in which you could parse the error string to detect out of focus, but you haven't installed your callback so libgphoto2 isn't using it. Use `gp_log_add_func` to install your callback.

Also, you're passing the return value of `camera.capture` to `gp.check_result`. This is incorrect as `camera.capture` already checks the result and raises an exception if there's an error.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that I didn't actually callback. But why do we assign callback object? Is there any use? I edited my code; is filtering callback message by error code a good way to reduce error logs?

Comment: A callback function is the only way to receive log messages from libgphoto2. You wanted to know if your camera had reported "out of focus", so you need a callback that parses the messages to detect this.

Comment: i see, i need to assign callback object when scoped inside a function

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out the name of the logger, you can add your own handler to it and do your own log processing.

Calling "getLogger" with your camera library's name would get you the logger.

Calling AddHandler on that logger with a custom handler would allow you to do your own log processing for logs coming from that logger.

Please see [Python's Logging Cookbook for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Hope this helps